# Android startActivityForResult with an intent and wait for user's response to the dialogfragment on the other activity that was started by the intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-dialogfragment

I use intent to start an activity (Activity A) from a fragment of another activity.
Activity A has a short game followed by a dialog (dialogfragment) asking if a user wants to save the result or not.

```
//code from the fragment
int requestCode = 100;
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), CoordinationTest.class);
i.putExtra("requestCode", requestCode);
startActivityForResult(i,requestCode);
```

However, when the activity A is finished before the dialog appears is goes right back to the previous fragment of the other activity.

```
//code in the activity that is called by the intent

stopDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "StopDialog");

if(getIntent().getExtras() != null ) {
    int requestCode = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("requestCode");
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SCAT) {
        setResult(RESULT_CODE_OK);
        finish();
    }
}
```

How should I fix this problem? I want to have the dialog before it goes back to the previous activity with the result.

I tried overriding onDismiss() method so that I can wait until the dialog is dismissed, but it didn't work.

Thank you!!